# On Upgrading Gradle for flutter(to 7.0.4) , I'm getting below issues

Tags: flutter, gradle, flutter-dependencies

A problem occurred configuring root project 'flutter_module'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Cannot resolve external dependency com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4 because no repositories are defined.
> Required by:
> project :

Possible solution:

- Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at

Answer (score 0):

where do you exactly change `Gradle`? did you chane `gradle-wrapper.properties` inside `projectFolder/android/gradle/wrapper`?
if you didn't. change it to this.

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-all.zip
```

Comment: Yes, I have changed the gradle version to 7.0.2 in gradle-wrapper.properties, but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You should install the Upgrade Assistant for consistent upgrades